# Having issues appending values to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I am having an issue appending the correct values to a python array. i have a code snipped right here:

```
p = np.zeros(8)
h = [2,3,7,4,5,6,1,9]
h = np.array(h)
for i in (0,7):
    if (h[i] >= 5):
        p[i]=1
    else:
        p[i]=3
p
```

The output that I'm expecting is [3,3,1,3,1,1,3,1], but for some reason I keep getting [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]. It seems like the first and last array values are read and appending correctly, but all the other elements are not. I am sure that it's just some silly error, but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: You are missing `range` in your `for` loop...

Comment: Good eye, thanks for that comment, thats what it was missing

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(h>5, 1, 3)
```

Output:

```
array([3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s the for loop?
does for i in h: work?

Answer (score 0):

This could have been solved if you used a print statement to debug, and this sounds like homework to be honest.

Change

```
for i in (0,7):
```

to

```
for i in range(0,8):
```

With (0, 7) you are just looping through 0 and 7 not 0 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tuple with 2 elements, not a range, for your loop. You want

```
for i in range(0,8):
```

Or even just

```
for i in range(8):
```